# Why i cannot access a label by id in mxml?

Tags: flex4, flex-spark

Maybe this question is too simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <s:Label id="label1"/>
    <fx:Script>
        public function setMsg(msg:String):void
        {
            label1.text = msg;
        }
    </fx:Script>
</s:View>
```

There's a run time error because label1 is null.
But when I change s:View to s:Group, everything's OK.
Why?

PS: put the label in SkinableContainer will also has this problem

Comment: You need to access label after the `creationComplete` event is dispatched.  Showing code of when `setMsg` is called would help debug the issue.

Comment: OK, to be precise, in the app's creationComplete, i new the view and setMsg before add it as a child/element.

Answer (score 1):

Components are instanciated asynchronously. You may want to try this implementation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
  <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
    private var _message:String, _messageChanged:Boolean;

    public function get message():String {
      return _message;
    }

    [Bindable("messageChanged")]
    public function set message(value:String):void {
      if (_message == value) {
        return;
      }
      _message = value;
      _messageChanged = true;
      invalidateProperties();
      dispatchEvent(new Event('messageChanged'));

    }

    override protected function commitProperties():void {
      super.commitProperties();
      if (_messageChanged) {
        _messageChanged = false;
        label1.text = _message;
      }
    }
    ]]>
  </fx:Script>

  <s:Label id="label1"/>
</s:View>
```

This is based on the Flex component live cycle, which lets you type a bit, but with a template it's ok if you can't/don't want to use data binding like in this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
  <fx:Script>

    [Bindable]
    private var _message:String;

    public function setMsg(msg:String):void
    {
      _message = msg;
    }
  </fx:Script>

  <s:Label id="label1" text="{_message}"/>
</s:View>
```

This example is might me a good choice as well - depending on your needs.

Comment: I don't understand the life cycle yet, but I tried the second approach, it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Now I thought the problem is not completely solved. If I need to call label1.addChild() from within creationComplete, there are still errors. I think it's the same problem?

Comment: When the Label is declared in MXML, it is automatically added. It seems like you have to add the view.